# Shopify linklists iteration

Tags: hyperlink, shopify

Is it possible to iterate through the Shopify linklists?

Currently I'm doing this to print all the items in all the menus:

```
{% assign menuHandles = "menu-1-handle|menu-2-handle|menu-3-handle" | split: "|" %}

{% for list in menuHandles %}
  {% for link in linklists[list].links %}
    <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This requires hard coding the menu names and i'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been added! Fast turnaround. :D

```
{% for linklist in linklists %}
    {{ linklist.handle }}
{% endfor %}
```